# Spring boot rest api: how to respond gracefully if Request Body is sent in incorrect format?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Let's say we have Spring boot api endpoint:

**Controller**

```
...
public String registerUser(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {
   ...
}
```

**User**

```
class User {
   @NotNull
   private Integer age;

   @NotNull
   private String name; 
   ...
}
```

When I send a request with a missing field, for example, `age` spring respond with a nice message explaining that `age` param is missing with property path, something like:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2016-12-20T18:44:29.450+0000",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
  "errors": [
    {
      "defaultMessage": "may not be nullt",
      "objectName": "user",
      "field": "age",
      ...
```

But if I provide `age` param as String in a request:

```
{
   age: "somestring"
}
```

I get `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException` ... `Could not read document: Can not deserialize value of type java.lang.Integer from String` with information in which method, line this exception occurred (Which I do not want to reveal).

But is there any way to respond such an exception in a format like missing age?

Something like:

```
"errors": [
        {
          "defaultMessage": "incorrect format",
          "objectName": "user",
          "field": "age",
          ...
```

Comment: One more useful blog https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling

Answer (score 5):

You will want a `@ControllerAdvice` bean to catch that exception and handle it appropriately. From https://blog.jayway.com/2013/02/03/improve-your-spring-rest-api-part-iii/, the code might look something like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        Throwable mostSpecificCause = ex.getMostSpecificCause();
        ErrorMessage errorMessage;
        if (mostSpecificCause != null) {
            String exceptionName = mostSpecificCause.getClass().getName();
            String message = mostSpecificCause.getMessage();
            errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(exceptionName, message);
        } else {
            errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(errorMessage, headers, status);
    }
}
```

Of course you can modify the response to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you, I do it with this way already, but is there any build in way?

Comment: Not that I know of. It does seem like something Spring itself should handle though. Perhaps a feature request?

Comment: This answer is how you do it. The build in way is that the throw exception is handled by the servlet-containers error handling mechanism, which typically produce a HTML page.